# Categorizing Just Imported Posts

Tags: categories, import, tumblr

I just imported a bunch of posts to my WordPress site, from Tumblr, using the

```
Tools -> Import
```

menu.  All my content is pulled into WordPress.  Yay!

Next -- I want to drop all the posts from this Tumblr site into a new category.  There doesn't appear to be a way to do this via the UI that isn't incredibly tedious (short of visually inspecting a title, selecting it in the Posts grid, doing an edit, etc).

Is there some way I can mass select just the recently imported posts?  Or some way I can programmatically do this is I know the post's database ID? (since all the imported posts are the most recent items in the database, I can get their IDs pretty easily).  Is there a way I can, at import time, say "put all the posts you're going to import into this category"?  Is there some solution I'm not thinking of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a super sexy solution, but I ended up installing the [Reveal IDs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-ids-for-wp-admin-25/) plugin, which let me sort by ID.  Then, using *Screen Options*, I maxed out the number of posts to display until all the recently imported items were showing.  This allowed me to make a mass edit on the posts to drop them into the new category I wanted.

Unfortunately, by default, Apache and PHP didn't like the super long POST urls that resulted.  I also had to (temporarily) max out a few URL related apache config variables.

```
# Apache Configuration
LimitRequestLine 40000
LimitRequestFieldSize 40000
```

and a similar PHP ini setting

```
max_input_vars=40000
```

Once I made my edits I removed these variable customizations to prevent future DDOS style abuse of my system.

Answer (score 0):

For changing the category from Tumblr to another one  for that you need to create another caregory at

```
<pre> Posts -> Categories -> Add New </pre>
```

first and than filter categories by Tumblr

[image]

And than all Tumblr category's Posts disaplay and do QUICK EDIT for changing the categories.

[image]

Comment: I might be missing something, but the tumblr importer didn't create a tumblr category for me.  It just imported the posts without a new category